# cluster prototypes of som results in object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Tags: r

I try to follow this [tutorial](http://en.proft.me/2016/11/29/modeling-self-organising-maps-r/) more precisely this code:

```
groups = 3
iris.hc = cutree(hclust(dist(iris.som$codes)), groups)

# plot
plot(iris.som, type="codes", bgcol=rainbow(groups)[iris.hc])

#cluster boundaries
add.cluster.boundaries(iris.som, iris.hc)
```

However, the bit:

```
dist(iris.som$codes)
```

gives me:

```
(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `dist` needs a numeric matrix as input but the object `iris.som$codes` is a list not a matrix:

```
str(iris.som$codes)

List of 1
 $ : num [1:25, 1:4] -1.353 -0.933 -0.523 0.321 0.569 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:25] "V1" "V2" "V3" "V4" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width" "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
```

Hence you must use `dist(iris.som$codes[[1]])` in your code:

```
library("kohonen")
iris.sc = scale(iris[, 1:4])
iris.grid = somgrid(xdim = 5, ydim=5, topo="hexagonal")
iris.som = som(iris.sc, grid=iris.grid, rlen=100, alpha=c(0.05,0.01))

iris.hc = cutree(hclust(dist(iris.som$codes[[1]])), groups)

plot(iris.som, type="codes", bgcol=rainbow(groups)[iris.hc])
add.cluster.boundaries(iris.som, iris.hc)
```

[image]